# Visa status and limited term driver's license in NJ

Tags: driving-license

I just surrendered my NY license and received a NJ one but found that it's limited term only valid for one year although my visa status is indicated as valid until 2023.

I was wondering if this is a NJ thing. In NY, when i renewed my license, they made it valid for 10 years.

If it's standard practice to make it valid only for one year first time I get an NJ license, will it be valid longer than one year next time I renew my license?

Comment: It's probably got to do with Real ID.  What is your status, and, more importantly, what is the expiration date on your I-94?  When did you last renew your license in New York (and are you sure it was 10 years and not 8)?